# Gitlab CI/CD with Kubernetes kind

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress, kind

I created Kind cluster with following config file and was connected to private hosted gitlab.

```
kind: Cluster
networking:
  apiServerAddress: "X.X.X.X"
# add to the apiServer certSANs the name of the docker (dind) service in order to be able to reach the cluster through it
kubeadmConfigPatchesJSON6902:
  - group: kubeadm.k8s.io
    version: v1beta2
    kind: ClusterConfiguration
    patch: |
      - op: add
        path: /apiServer/certSANs/-
        value: docker
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
    kubeadmConfigPatches:
    - |
      kind: InitConfiguration
      nodeRegistration:
        kubeletExtraArgs:
          node-labels: "ingress-ready=true"
    extraPortMappings:
    - containerPort: 80
      hostPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      listenAddress: "X.X.X.X"
    - containerPort: 443
      hostPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
      listenAddress: "X.X.X.X"
  - role: worker
```

After that I successfully Integrated my cluster and installed applications including helm tiller, Ingress and gitlab runner. The first problem occurred was in the displaying of Ingress Endpoint IP which keeps on loading
[image]

Meanwhile I tried to debug it and on Inspection it was found gitlab-managed-app-ingress external Ip was remaining pending. I tried to install Ingress manually with node port and also updated the Auto-DevOps template on gitlab and forcefully changed the ingress endpoints with following line in gitlab-ci.yml.

```
variables:
  KUBE_INGRESS_BASE_DOMAIN: X.X.X.X
```

After that the pipeline went successful until the deployment on staging. It fails on staging with error

[image]

Can someone suggest me a little bit on this? Correct me If I have done something wrong and stupid. Thanks in advance

Comment: could you please share the kubernetes version?

Comment: Seems you need to change the `apiVersion` on your deployment spec. Try to use `apps/v1`. Please share your kubernetes version and your spec yaml.